# How to prevent Activity automatically open in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am developing an app that contains an IntentService to send a request to a server when the app is in background and the response from server will start the activity using an intent. Problem is that it opens the activity automatically without any user interaction when the app is in background. How to avoid this only open activity when app comes to foreground.

Here is my IntentService code:

```
public class OTPIntentService extends IntentService {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public CRegistrationSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement;
    public String m_szMobileNumber, m_szEncryptedPassword;
    public String TAG = "OTPIntentService";

    public OTPIntentService() {
        super("OTPIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Context m_Context = getApplicationContext();// get activity context
        m_oSessionManagement = new CRegistrationSessionManagement(m_Context);// creating object of Registartion session
        // retreive user data from shared preferencce........
        HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getRegistrationDetails();// getting String from Regisatrtion session
        m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CRegistrationSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// get password from registartion session
        m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CRegistrationSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILENUMBER).trim();// get mobile number from registartion session

        try {
            String json;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);
            jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);
            jsonObject.put("otpCode", COTPVerificationDataStorage.getInstance().getM_szOtp());

            json = jsonObject.toString();
            System.out.println("Request:-" + json);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_szOtpverification, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                    try {
                        if (response.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {

                        } else if (response.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("OTP MisMatch")) {
                            if (NetworkUtil.isAppIsInBackground(m_Context)) {

                            } else {
                                Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }

                        } else if (response.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("otpCode Can Not Be Empty")) {
                            if (NetworkUtil.isAppIsInBackground(m_Context)) {

                            } else {
                                Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                }
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(m_Context);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but you need at least one `Activity` to launch the app

Comment: see I have MainActivity and OtpVerification Activity ...from OtpVerification activity I send Intent service and after that I close the app the intent service send request to server and from response it automatically open activity which mentioned when app is in background.

Comment: You can do something like that Keep the user on OTP screen and run a `AsyncTask` that will fetch the status of the OTP. Check in the response, if true than jump to next `Activity` else something.

Comment: and what  about when user close app during this

Comment: are you receiving OTP via normal message?

Comment: yes.....I do......

Comment: are you using `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the message?

Comment: sorry i distracted. what is the issue. you said it opens the app without user interaction. as it is a `Service` it does not have an interface. so how to you want to start the app if the otp is valid and verified?

Comment: Do you really need the Service to start the activity directly?  It might be easier to use an event bus so that other activities can know when the work is complete and start up the next service.

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` that starts the `Service` should create a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for the response. When `onReceive()` in the `BroadcastReceiver` is called, it can update the UI. If the app is in the background, the user will see the updated UI when the he brings the app to the foreground. If the app is already in the foreground when `onReceive()` is called, the user will see the UI updates immediately.

In your `Service`, to pass the data back to the `Activity`, you will want to send a broadcast `Intent` using `sendBroadcast()` instead of using `startActivity()`.